# Restructuring the database after deleting a row

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

So, I have a few numbered EditTexts on my screen. These are shown upon retreival of 
info from the database. But my onLongClickListener() is to delete a particular EditText. This happens and the same is reflected in the database. However the numbers w.r.t the entry is to be updated.

```
>Eg:-   
>I have 4 EditTexts....
>I delete the second one....
>The database is numbered 1,3,4...
>I now want it to be renumbered as 1,2,3.

What logic may I use?
```

Comment: With MS SQL Server 2005+ you can use `SET Num = ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY Num)` to achieve this. I've never used sqllite so not sure if it's supported. Hopefully this will give you something to research? [Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the number that was deleted, and then do:

```
update t
    set num = num-1
    where num > <val deleted>
```

You have to set up the query with the just deleted value.  This does result in updating many, many rows, so it may not be a good idea.

Comment: Check

[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097751/convert-a-query-from-rawquery-to-update) and 
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099756/decrementing-a-value-not-working)