# Decrementing a value not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a column that is to be decremented by 1. The following code doesn't seem to be working.

```
ContentValues dataToUpdate = new ContentValues();                          
dataToUpdate .put(MARKER_ID, MARKER_ID+"-1");
String where = IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +imageId+ " AND "+MARKER_ID+" > "+markerId+";";
int resultUpdate = db.update(TABLE_DEFECTS, dataToUpdate, where, null);
```

I also tried `rawQuery`. That didn't work as well. 
**MARKER_ID** is the name of the column.

```
  String restructureDbQuesry="UPDATE "+TABLE_DEFECTS+" SET "+MARKER_ID+" = "+MARKER_ID+"-1"+" WHERE "+IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +imageId+ " AND "+MARKER_ID+" > "+markerId;
  Cursor resultUpdate = db.rawQuery(restructureDbQuesry,null);
```

resulting query after an iteration:

```
UPDATE defects SET Marker_Id = Marker_Id-1 WHERE Image_Id = 2 AND Marker_Id > 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, after you execute queries that return nothing in the cursor, we have to perform some operation to the cursor.

So, `resultUpdate.moveToFirst();` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to used like this.

```
 public int updateCounter(int num,String number,int duration, String currentDate){
    ContentValues cv =new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DIALED_CALL, num-1);
    cv.put(CALL_DURATION, duration);
    cv.put(CALL_DATE, currentDate);
     return db.update(TABLE_LOGS, cv, PHONE_NUMBER + " = ? ", new String []{number});        

}
```

try this also change in your code.

```
dataToUpdate .put(MARKER_ID, MARKER_ID-1);
```

Comment: Sorry the first party of it felt irrelavent. I didn't see the following part. This will make it dataToUpdate.put(String,int). It resulted in throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line:

```
dataToUpdate .put(MARKER_ID, MARKER_ID+"-1");
```

If MARKER_ID is the name of the column (lets assume its 'markerid') then you will set the column to the string value "markerid-1".

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought. So, what would be the solution?

Comment: But when I checked the DB the string hadn't changed. It's still the same.

Comment: Use an SQL statement like this: `UPDATE table SET markerid = markerid -1 WHERE ...your where clause...` with a raw query.

Comment: I tried this as well:-

`String restructureDbQuesry="UPDATE "+TABLE_DEFECTS+" SET "+MARKER_ID+" = "+MARKER_ID+"-1"+" WHERE "+IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +imageId+ " AND "+MARKER_ID+" > "+markerId;`



`Cursor resultUpdate = db.rawQuery(restructureDbQuesry,null);`

Comment: The above also has the same issue.

Comment: are you sure that there is a row matching the where clause?

Comment: Yes, there is. In the Sqlite browser, the same query will ensure the update. The SAME query.

Comment: [Check this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097751/convert-a-query-from-rawquery-to-update)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String restructureDbQuesry="UPDATE "+TABLE_DEFECTS+" SET "+MARKER_ID+" = "+MARKER_ID+"-1"+" WHERE "+IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +imageId+ " AND "+MARKER_ID+" > "+markerId;
db.execSQL(restructureDbQuesry,null);
```