# sqlite update query issue

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a query that has to decrement a value in the DB by 1.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068983/restructuring-the-database-after-deleting-a-row) is the link for the actual question and the answers that I received

```
update t
set num = num-1
where num > <val deleted>
```

Now the above is updating the actual number in the database to the string 'num-1'. How do I decrement the value and not change the value to the string 'num-1'. The data type of the column is an integer.

The actual query is:

```
ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();                          
dataToInsert.put(MARKER_ID, MARKER_ID+"-1");
String where = /*IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +imageId+ " AND "+*/MARKER_ID+" > "+markerId;
int resultUpdate = db.update(TABLE_DEFECTS, dataToInsert, where, null);
```

Comment: please specify data type of num in question.

Comment: About which string you are talking?

Comment: @DynamicMind As said, it is an integer.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have reframed the question. please have a look

Comment: this will not work with the update method. you'll need the rawQuery

Answer (score 0):

`update` is a method specifically designed not to accept any such computation. You are expected to put in the contentValues the exact value you want.

For your purpose, you need `rawQuery`:

```
db.rawQuery("update " + TABLE_DEFECTS + " set " + MARKER_ID + " = " + MARKER_ID + " -1 where " + MARKER_ID + " > ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(markerId) });
```

Comment: This didn't update the DB. :( My exact query is:-

`Cursor test = db.rawQuery("update " + TABLE_DEFECTS + " set " + MARKER_ID + " = " + MARKER_ID + " -1 where "+IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +(imageId+1)+ " AND "+ MARKER_ID + " > ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(markerId) });`

Comment: No error. The cursor doesn't have any value, indicating the query has executed without any errors. But, I can clearly see rows matching the criteria.